# Linux grep command in Perl script not working

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have a grep command which works on Linux command prompt:
`grep -Po 'rand_num=\K[^ ]*' log.txt`
This command prints the number after `rand_num=` in my log.txt file.  But I need this command in perl script.  I tried

```
my $rand_number;
$rand_number = system("grep -Po 'rand_num=\K[^ ]*' log.txt");
print "Random number = $rand_number";
```

But it doesn't work. I tried
`` $rand_number = `grep -Po 'rand_num=\K[^ ]*' log.txt`; ``
But that also didn't work

Can someone tell what is mistake here and how got get it working?

Comment: `system` does not give the program output as return value, it gives the program's exit status. Which is not useful in this case. You need backticks or `qx()`.

Answer (score 4):

Once in a Perl script, there is no need to go out to the system to run an external command (that uses Perl's regex!) -- for something Perl can do really well, and really better.

Here are some ways to do this.

Open a file and read line by line, fetching the needed phrase from each line

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @random_numbers;
while (<$fh>) { 
    push @random_numbers, /rand_num=(\S+)/g;
}
close $fh;
say for @random_numbers;
```

Or read all lines at once and pass them through a filter of sorts

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @random_numbers = map { /rand_num=(\S+)/g } <$fh>;

close $fh;
say for @random_numbers;
```

I use [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) to extract the phrase from each line as [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) would return whole lines that satisfy the condition. If there is no match an empty list is returned, "disappearing" into the overall return list from `map`, or into an uninitialized array if nothing whatsoever was matched.  This way `map` acts as a filter.

The above captures the (presumed<sup>†</sup>) numbers from all `rand_num=NUM` on each line, if there can be more than one on a line.  If also presumes that the filename `$file` has somehow been read into the script.

Or, use the "null" filehandle (with no need for a filename)

```
my @random_numbers;
while (<>) { ... }                    # same block as in first example

#  OR 

my @random_numbers = map { ... } <>;  # same block as in second example
```

if the script is invoked with that file name on the command line, `script.pl file`.

This works because the "magic" [diamond operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) (`<>`) reads line by line files submitted on the command line.  All of them though -- if the script runs as `script.pl file1 file2 ...` it will do the above through all those files.

One can also read the whole file into a string ("slurp" it) and then work with that. This is helpful when patterns of interest span multiple lines. Let's also use a library, here [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use Path::Tiny;  # path()

my @rn = path($file)->slurp =~ /.../g;  # same regex as before
```

Now the regex match is [bound](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) to the string returned by the `slurp` method, which contains the whole file. Since it is done in the list context, imposed on the regex by the list-assignment, all matches are returned in a list, which is assigned to `@rn`.

I boldly assume that your (*every*) script starts with

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

For the [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature) `say` we also need either `use feature 'say';` or to `use` a version of Perl which includes it or another large framework which does.

---

<sup>†</sup>  The regex in the question matches all non-whitespace characters following `rand_num=`.  If it is absolutely certain (huh) that these can only be numbers as expected, then so be it.

Otherwise, one could be more careful and use a pattern that will only match an actual number.  Or, capture as above and then check that it is indeed a number, using `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util)

Comment: Thanks a lot Zdim !  I will try your option also for learning.  Other solution worked though. I appreciate.

Comment: @MukeshPatel  Welcome :)   More is coming -- I will edit this quite a bit, to add

Comment: @MukeshPatel Added (a lot) to the answer. Let me know if there are questions

Answer (score 2):

You've found yourself trapped in [quoting hell](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/revision/Quoting+hell?V=52). Perl is treating the `\K` as an escape sequence and removing the backslash in the actual string `system` sees. You can double-escape the backslash if you want

```
system("grep -Po 'rand_num=\\K[^ ]*' log.txt");
```

or you can use one of Perl's [myriad of ways](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) to write a string that prohibits backslashes from expanding at all.

```
system q(grep -Po 'rand_num=\K[^ ]*' log.txt);
```

This may look weird, and if your editor isn't designed for Perl, it may not understand it either (To be honest, I'm surprised StackOverflow's code highlighter is handling it correctly). But `q(...)` is equivalent to `'...'` except that you can use single quotes inside of the former.

Comment: Thanks a lot Silvio. \\K worked. Thanks for your quick response. I really appreciate.

Comment: @MukeshPatel Since this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it, and maybe the other too if it also helped. And please consider accepting the one that solved your problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: This answer is wrong. `system` does not give the grep capture as return value, it gives the exit status of the program that was run. The escape is also messed up, but this would not fix the problem. You would need to use backticks or `qx()` to get the return value. The better version is to use Perl for the extraction, like zdim does.